# Sharepoint 2010 column missing or hidden?

Tags: 2010, list, site-column

I created several site columns to build multiple lists on a new SP 2010 site.  In one of the new lists one of the columns has gone missing and I cannot reference, view, or update entries in the column.  However, the column shows up on new forms for the content type associated to that column.

I'm completely baffled how this occurred and how I get that column back.
I'd like to avoid rebuilding the list entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can check/update field settings with [sharepoint manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/35932).
You have to check

- ShowInDisplayForm
- ShowInEditForm
- ShowInListSettings
- ShowInNewForm
- ShowInVersionHistor
- ShowInViewForms

  properties.

Answer (score 0):

What type of field is that? Did you set ReadOnly or Hidden property to true? You can try setting property ShowInNewForm, ShowInDisplayForm, ShowInEditForm to true, like below.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://test"
$list = $web.Lists["listname"]
$fields = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("nameofcolumn")
$field.ShowInEditForm = $true
$field.ShowInNewForm = $true
$field.ShowInDisplayForm = $true
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: It is a choice field (3 choices, checkboxes).  I'm unsure how to run those commands?  I've been interacting with our Sharepoint via designer 2010 and the web.

Comment: If it helps at all, if I try to edit the content type on the list in Sharepoint Designer 2012, I get: Could not load requested object.  Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object.  Object returned by the following call stack is null. ""

Comment: Also, if I edit the content type via the web I can edit it just fine, but the column does not show up.  It only shows up under the section to set the order on a new item form.